# How can I set timeout on client node for a data node of elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, garbage-collection, jvm

So I have one client node and 2 nodes which are both master and data.

The data node have 32GB RAM of which 16GB is allocated to heap for elasticsearch.

The server run perfectly for most of the data expect during GC phases. The server stops responding. I tried different configurations but was unable to bring GC time down.

Now the problem is even if there is GC going on one node, the whole cluster dies.
Is there a way that I can set timeout for ES data node on my ES client.

So when GC is happening on that node it would timeout and ES client will return the result it collected from one of the node and not wait for complete data to return from both node.

Is there a way to do this.

If someone wants I can share my JVM settings for elasticsearch and elasticsearch.yaml file also.

Logs for GC : 
[2016-01-28 12:36:27,200][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [Main-Server-M2XLarge-2] [gc][old][91418][327] duration [11.1s], collections [1]/[11.6s], total [11.1s]/[24.6m], memory [6gb]->[4.7gb]/[15.5gb], all_pools {[young] [411.7mb]->[14.4mb]/[532.5mb]}{[survivor] [38.1mb]->[0b]/[66.5mb]}{[old] [5.6gb]->[4.7gb]/[14.9gb]}

[2016-01-28 12:38:06,227][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [Main-Server-M2XLarge-2] [gc][old][91506][328] duration [10.8s], collections [1]/[11.7s], total [10.8s]/[24.8m], memory [5.8gb]->[4.8gb]/[15.5gb], all_pools {[young] [346mb]->[1.1mb]/[532.5mb]}{[survivor] [46.6mb]->[0b]/[66.5mb]}{[old] [5.4gb]->[4.8gb]/[14.9gb]}

[2016-01-28 12:38:16,819][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [Main-Server-M2XLarge-2] [gc][old][91507][329] duration [10s], collections [1]/[10.5s], total [10s]/[24.9m], memory [4.8gb]->[4.8gb]/[15.5gb], all_pools {[young] [1.1mb]->[479kb]/[532.5mb]}{[survivor] [0b]->[0b]/[66.5mb]}{[old] [4.8gb]->[4.8gb]/[14.9gb]}

[2016-01-28 12:38:36,551][INFO ][monitor.jvm              ] [Main-Server-M2XLarge-2] [gc][old][91508][331] duration [19.6s], collections [2]/[19.7s], total [19.6s]/[25.3m], memory [4.8gb]->[4.5gb]/[15.5gb], all_pools {[young] [479kb]->[33.6mb]/[532.5mb]}{[survivor] [0b]->[0b]/[66.5mb]}{[old] [4.8gb]->[4.4gb]/[14.9gb]}

Comment: Elasticsearch recommend against adjusting GC: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_don_8217_t_touch_these_settings.html#_garbage_collector. Have you changed it to a stop-the-world collector? Concurrent mark-sweep should have minimal pauses.

Comment: Also, I take it you mean 16GB, not 16B?

Comment: no I did not change the GC. Changed some other settings like survivor size, young pool size. CMS does have long pauses thats why people are shifting to G1GC to avoid it. and yes its 16GB

Comment: When GC happens nothing works on that node (ping responding, queries responses etc). Looking at tunning the GC is not the way to go. And I don't think there is a timeout mechanism in ES. The advice is to look at why it's taking too much time for GC to happen. Speaking of, how much time an old GC takes?

Comment: It currently takes about 1 min. Unable to attach logs. Updating question.

Comment: I see no old GC taking 1 min. I see 19.6 sec, 10 sec, 10.8 sec, 11.1 sec. But this is concerning. The times are long and there are even two GCs running one after the other. This means you do have significant memory pressure. Do you have swapping enabled on the OS?

Comment: Yes it sums upto 1 min..one after the other. No we have not created any swap space on the instance. Also set the mlockall flag to true.

Comment: Use `GET /_nodes/stats/os` to see if you have swap free or used. And use `GET /_nodes/process` to see if `mlockall` is indeed `true`. You can have it set in config file, but it can fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101896/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-andrei-stefan).